# Duplicidad del menú después de usar menu setup

Tags: gvnix

Mi problema es que después de ejecutar **menu setup** de GvNIX  y actualizar con bootstrap las vistas y desplegar el proyecto todo funcionaba bien.
Comandos utilizados para actualizar un proyecto ya creado con Spring Roo (con menú ya creado con Spring Roo):

- `finder add --finderName findCbCountrysByCountry --class ~.domain.CbCountry`
- `finder add --finderName findCbCountrysByDescription`
- `web mvc all --package ~.web`
- `web mvc scaffold --class ~.web.CbEnterpriseListController --backingType ~.domain.CbEnterprise --path cbEnterpriselist`
- `web mvc finder all`
- `web mvc jquery setup`
- `web mvc jquery all`
- `web mvc datatables setup`
- `web mvc bootstrap setup`
- **`menu setup`**
- `web mvc bootstrap update`
- `jpa gvnix setup`
- `jpa batch all --package org.xulescode.batch`
- `web mvc batch setup`
- `web mvc batch all`
- `web mvc bootstrap update`

Este es el contenido de `menu.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<gvnix-menu id="_menu" rooMenuBasePath="/">
<menu-item id="c_cbcurrency" labelCode="menu_category_cbcurrency_label" name="Cbcurrency">
        <menu-item hidden="false" id="i_cbcurrency_new" labelCode="menu_item_cbcurrency_new_label" messageCode="global_menu_new" roles="" url="/cbcurrencys?form"/>
    <menu-item hidden="false" id="i_cbcurrency_list" labelCode="menu_item_cbcurrency_list_label" messageCode="global_menu_list" roles="" url="/cbcurrencys?page=1&amp;size=${empty param.size ? 10 : param.size}"/>
    </menu-item>
<menu-item id="c_cbpaymentmethod" labelCode="menu_category_cbpaymentmethod_label" name="Cbpaymentmethod">
        <menu-item hidden="false" id="i_cbpaymentmethod_new" labelCode="menu_item_cbpaymentmethod_new_label" messageCode="global_menu_new" roles="" url="/cbpaymentmethods?form"/>
    <menu-item hidden="false" id="i_cbpaymentmethod_list" labelCode="menu_item_cbpaymentmethod_list_label" messageCode="global_menu_list" roles="" url="/cbpaymentmethods?page=1&amp;size=${empty param.size ? 10 : param.size}"/>
    </menu-item>
<menu-item id="c_cbenterprise" labelCode="menu_category_cbenterprise_label" name="Cbenterprise">
        <menu-item hidden="false" id="i_cbenterprise_new" labelCode="menu_item_cbenterprise_new_label" messageCode="global_menu_new" roles="" url="/cbenterprises?form"/>
    <menu-item hidden="false" id="i_cbenterprise_list" labelCode="menu_item_cbenterprise_list_label" messageCode="global_menu_list" roles="" url="/cbenterprises?page=1&amp;size=${empty param.size ? 10 : param.size}"/>
    </menu-item>
<menu-item id="c_cbcountry" labelCode="menu_category_cbcountry_label" name="Cbcountry">
        <menu-item hidden="false" id="i_cbcountry_new" labelCode="menu_item_cbcountry_new_label" messageCode="global_menu_new" roles="" url="/cbcountrys?form"/>
    <menu-item hidden="false" id="i_cbcountry_list" labelCode="menu_item_cbcountry_list_label" messageCode="global_menu_list" roles="" url="/cbcountrys?page=1&amp;size=${empty param.size ? 10 : param.size}"/>
    <menu-item hidden="false" id="fi_cbcountry_country" labelCode="menu_item_cbcountry_country_label" messageCode="global_menu_find" roles="" url="/cbcountrys?find=ByCountry&amp;form&amp;page=1&amp;size=${empty param.size ? 10 : param.size}"/>
    <menu-item hidden="false" id="fi_cbcountry_description" labelCode="menu_item_cbcountry_description_label" messageCode="global_menu_find" roles="" url="/cbcountrys?find=ByDescription&amp;form&amp;page=1&amp;size=${empty param.size ? 10 : param.size}"/>
    </menu-item>
<menu-item id="c_cblanguage" labelCode="menu_category_cblanguage_label" name="Cblanguage">
        <menu-item hidden="false" id="i_cblanguage_new" labelCode="menu_item_cblanguage_new_label" messageCode="global_menu_new" roles="" url="/cblanguages?form"/>
    <menu-item hidden="false" id="i_cblanguage_list" labelCode="menu_item_cblanguage_list_label" messageCode="global_menu_list" roles="" url="/cblanguages?page=1&amp;size=${empty param.size ? 10 : param.size}"/>
    </menu-item>
</gvnix-menu>
```

Y este es el contenido de menu.jspx (lo publico por que entiendo que está el contenido duplicado), pero no se bien por qué:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<div xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" xmlns:jsp="http://java.sun.com/JSP/Page" xmlns:menu="urn:jsptagdir:/WEB-INF/tags/menu" id="menu" version="2.0">
    <jsp:output omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
    <menu:menu id="_menu" z="user-managed">
        <menu:gvnixmenu/>
        <menu:category id="c_cbenterprise" z="2Xr1rR/7kZ7LSP9IgH+k1Ai4o9Y=">
            <menu:item id="i_cbenterprise_new" messageCode="global_menu_new" url="/cbEnterpriselist?form" z="zXwloohWqc3sfNrqCYkFY29VQDQ="/>
            <menu:item id="i_cbenterprise_list" messageCode="global_menu_list" url="/cbEnterpriselist?page=1&amp;size=${empty param.size ? 10 : param.size}" z="+k3352WYfccE8KEPqKU5L94OK1o="/>
        </menu:category>
        <menu:category id="c_cbcountry" z="3mKnVawC053Nr9dcHJJbO2xQ7Tw=">
            <menu:item id="i_cbcountry_new" messageCode="global_menu_new" url="/cbcountrys?form" z="AXjZfsgw3wdNtyR/LxQ6zRbxa7I="/>
            <menu:item id="i_cbcountry_list" messageCode="global_menu_list" url="/cbcountrys?page=1&amp;size=${empty param.size ? 10 : param.size}" z="oHWNBELqZS4DNnKL32prhBNyzik="/>
            <menu:item id="fi_cbcountry_country" messageCode="global_menu_find" url="/cbcountrys?find=ByCountry&amp;form&amp;page=1&amp;size=${empty param.size ? 10 : param.size}" z="pid8wlI3/Ic7bKjjg3tZQh+0ZOI="/>
            <menu:item id="fi_cbcountry_description" messageCode="global_menu_find" url="/cbcountrys?find=ByDescription&amp;form&amp;page=1&amp;size=${empty param.size ? 10 : param.size}" z="C+95Ce7nC1gAWtR/OnIOOXEPU24="/>
        </menu:category>
        <menu:category id="c_cbcurrency" z="0geytNlomHRFRjNypdM7Xu4xw20=">
            <menu:item id="i_cbcurrency_new" messageCode="global_menu_new" url="/cbcurrencys?form" z="QeMJUzkiYSrlgmlDB5dCA1xOiFI="/>
            <menu:item id="i_cbcurrency_list" messageCode="global_menu_list" url="/cbcurrencys?page=1&amp;size=${empty param.size ? 10 : param.size}" z="/BUVqo+GhOnnMbjDK8LEVw/vOkQ="/>
        </menu:category>
        <menu:category id="c_cbpaymentmethod" z="73O3LX34G7t4WognPtBJ+zyZXJM=">
            <menu:item id="i_cbpaymentmethod_new" messageCode="global_menu_new" url="/cbpaymentmethods?form" z="iblG2znIuooFCBix+6DTBMOwErQ="/>
            <menu:item id="i_cbpaymentmethod_list" messageCode="global_menu_list" url="/cbpaymentmethods?page=1&amp;size=${empty param.size ? 10 : param.size}" z="811LjpGJCstFqPCPxYzMtwrdAf8="/>
        </menu:category>
        <menu:category id="c_cblanguage" z="U+XiXRGSYBv9BWwdKUKZyrYEID8=">
            <menu:item id="i_cblanguage_new" messageCode="global_menu_new" url="/cblanguages?form" z="5ZO1hGYBs5WEOkLgdHNIeQxS318="/>
            <menu:item id="i_cblanguage_list" messageCode="global_menu_list" url="/cblanguages?page=1&amp;size=${empty param.size ? 10 : param.size}" z="2xtQM9F9QxHyS8ifCqoqtMu5jp4="/>
        </menu:category>
    </menu:menu>
</div>
```

¿La solución es simplemente eliminar el código de menu.jspx?¿Este código viene arrastrado del menú de spring roo ya que inicialmente empezé el proyecto con Spring Roo?

Answer (score 1):

Respondo a mi pregunta ya que ahora lo tengo claro.

> ¿La solución es simplemente eliminar el código de **menu.jspx**?

Si, nos quedamos con el **menú GvNIX** que se encuentra en **menu.xml** y que lo cargamos en **menu.jspx** con `, por lo tanto tenemos que eliminar el código de los menús generado por el menú general de Spring Roo.

> ¿Este código viene arrastrado del menú de Spring Roo ya que inicialmente empecé el proyecto con Spring Roo?

Si, el código de menú de Spring Roo se genera directamente sobre la clase **menu.jspx** a diferencia del **menú GvNIX** que se gestiona en el fichero **menu.xml** , y que nos permitirá vía consola Roo ir actualizando y modificando fácilmente la colocación de nuestro menú según nuestras necesidades.

Comment: Curioso, se supone que esto no debería pasar. Si miras https://github.com/DISID/gvnix-samples/blob/master/quickstart-app/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/views/menu.jspx verás que no coincide con el tuyo. Por algún motivo, gvNIX no ha actualizado ese fichero al ejecutar el `menu setup`.

Comment: ¿Puede que modificaras el `<menu:menu id="_menu" z="user-managed">` en el _menu.jspx_ antes de hacer el `menu setup`?

Answer (score 1):

El problema ya lo he solucionado eliminando manualmente los menús de Spring Roo, ahora el menu GvNIX me funcionan perfectamente, ya lo he utilizado creando nuevas entradas de menú y moviendo las entradas de sitio.

No puedo confirmar que no haya modificado el menu.jspx (creo que no, pero no lo puedo asegurar), lo que si te puedo mostrar es la secuencia de comandos utilizada hasta la generación del menú:

```
addon repository add --url http://repository.gvnix.org/index.xml
addon suite list --repository http://repository.gvnix.org/index.xml
addon suite install name --symbolicName org.gvnix.roo.addon.suite
!g lb
addon list
finder add --finderName findCbCountrysByCountry --class ~.domain.CbCountry
finder add --finderName findCbCountrysByDescription
web mvc all --package ~.web
web mvc scaffold --class ~.web.CbEnterpriseListController --backingType ~.domain.CbEnterprise --path cbEnterpriselist
web mvc finder all
web mvc jquery setup
web mvc jquery all
web mvc datatables setup
web mvc bootstrap setup
menu setup
web mvc bootstrap update
```

Un saludo

Answer (score 0):

El problema creo que está en que el fichero *menu.jspx* estaba modificado a mano antes de que pasase a gestionarlo gvNIX.

Como puedes ver, en este fichero *menu.jspx* tienes:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<div xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" xmlns:jsp="http://java.sun.com/JSP/Page" xmlns:menu="urn:jsptagdir:/WEB-INF/tags/menu" id="menu" version="2.0">
    <jsp:output omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
    <menu:menu id="_menu" z="user-managed">
        <menu:gvnixmenu/>
        <menu:category id="c_cbenterprise" z="2Xr1rR/7kZ7LSP9IgH+k1Ai4o9Y=">
        ....
        ...
```

La llamada al tag `<menu:gvnixmenu/>` es la que pinta el menú de gvNIX a partir del fichero `menu.xml` y, después tienes el resto que ya había generado Spring Roo. Se supone que en el comando de `menu setup` debería haber limpiado los elementos que genera Roo.

Par solucionarlo, simplemente deja el fichero tal y como está en el [ejemplo de github](https://github.com/DISID/gvnix-samples/blob/master/quickstart-app/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/views/menu.jspx) y debería de funcionar.

Si no habías modificado el fichero `menu.jspx` antes de ejecutar `menu setup`, por favor, crea un incidencia en el [github de gvNIX](https://github.com/gvSIGAssociation/gvnix) para tenerlo en cuenta.

Un saludo.

Comment: El problema ya lo he solucionado eliminando manualmente los menús de Spring Roo, ahora el menu GvNIX me funcionan perfectamente, ya lo he utilizado moviendo creando nuevas entradas de menú y moviendo las entradas de sitio.